# How to get position of nested object after the rotation of parent object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, movieclip

I have a big MovieClip object composed of many small MovieClip objects. After the rotation of parent object, the coordinates of nested objects are changed. But the x and y properties of nested objects remains the same it was before rotation of parent. How to get updated coordinates?

For example, there is an [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCGBm.png) composed of two circles. Local coordinates of small circle is -34 0. After [rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX4Oo.png) the coordinates of the small circle is still -34 0, but global coordinates was obviously changed. Is there a way to obtain new global coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The most straightforward way is to use [`localToGLobal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) function

In you example as3 can looks like:

```
//converts local (0, 0) of innerMc to global (stage) coordinates system 
var point:Point = innerMc.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));

//another way (for better understanding) - converts innerMc 
//coordinates in outerMc system (in your case it's (-34, 0)
var point2:Point = outerMc.localToGlobal(new Point(innerMc.x, innerMc.y));
```

Both options will give you the same result.

Comment: I don't believe localToGlobal takes rotation into account.  Though it's been so long since I've used it I don't recall for certain.

Comment: You can not believe for sure, but `localToGlobal` always counted any transformation on any of the parents :)